# Android Google Play Store App is not 64bit compliant

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play, 64-bit, x86-64

I use a native library in my app: https://www.portsip.com
I initiate it and use it by using a jar file:
`implementation files('src/main/libs/portsipvoipsdk.jar')`

I have this in my build.gradle of the app:

```
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23    // Android 6.0 (MarshMallow)
    targetSdkVersion 28 // Android 9 (Pie)
    applicationId applicationIdBase
    versionCode 94
    versionName '1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
```

Now if I analyse the APK, I see this: 
[image]

As you can see, there is no x86_64, just x86, arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a.
My question is: Because I don't really need the x86 architecture, Is it possible to remove it, so I only have arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a.
This shoud make it possible for me to upload my app to the play store, without needing to wait for the library I am using to update, correct?
And if so, any ideeas how I can remove that?

Comment: Yes, apparently you can just remove x86 support.  Any ISAs you do support at all need to include the 64-bit version, but you don't need to support every possible 64-bit ISA.

Comment: Thanks, I did manage to make it work by removing x86 support
Using this in packagingOptions: `exclude "lib/x86/**"`

Comment: Does this question need a canonical answer somewhere?  Or is there a better dup target?  There have (unsurprisingly) been a few recent variations of it tagged `[x86]` and/or `[x86-64]` recently.  I'm not sure if the one I picked is a good dup target or not; I don't do Android development myself.  (I follow x86-64 for asm and performance questions).

Comment: It was set as duplicate, so I could not answer it here. I told in a comment above how I fixed this issue, which is different from what the duplicate questions answer is. Now I don't know, what action to take regarding this question. If needed , it can be deleted if it's a duplicate.